# Datatable AJAX change on onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

Hello my Datatable ajax works on first onClick event but getting error after that

warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

This is my code

```
<table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border table table-striped table-bordered" data-page-length='25' style="width:100%"> </table>

<select class="form-control" style="  background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow;" asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "code", "productName"))" id="formulaId"></select>


      $("#formulaId").change(function () {
           

            var popup, dataTable;
            var entity = 'Quote';
            var apiurl = '/api/' + entity + '/index';
            var formulaId = $('#formulaId').val();

            alert(formulaId);
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    destroy: true,
                    retrieve: true,
                    paging: false,
                    searching: false,
                    "url": apiurl + '/' + formulaId,
                    "type": 'GET',
                    "datatype": 'json'
                   
                },

                //   data: dataSet,
                columns: [
                    { title: "Item Key", data: "itemKey" },
                    { title: "Description", data: "description" },
                    { title: "Pounds", data: "pound" },

                    { title: "Current Cost", data: "cost" },
                    {
                        title: "New Cost", data: "cost",
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {


                            return '<input type="number" class ="price-input"  value="' + data + '" style="background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow;">';

                        }
                    },
                    { title: "Unit", data: "unit" },
                    {
                        title: "Quantity", data: "quantity"

                    },
                    {
                        title: "Total", data: function (data, type, row) {

                            return '<input type="number" readonly  value="' + data.totalCost + '" style="background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow;">';

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        title: "New Total", "data": "totalCost",
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<input type="number" readonly class ="price-input"  value="' + data + '" style="background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow;">';

                        }
                    }

                ],
```

My question is it was working for first time,  even for the second time I am getting formulaId in alert but after that I am getting warning for dataTable. Please guide me.

Comment: Per the documentation linked to the DataTables site `The retrieve and destroy options are mutually exclusive and cannot be used together (doing so will result in undefined behaviour).`

Comment: In your DataTable set-up you have placed a number of options inside the `ajax` option which are not valid in that location. The `ajax` option does not support `destroy`, `retrieve`, `paging` or `searching`. Those are top-level DataTables options.

Comment: If you want to repeatedly call your DataTables Ajax source, without needing to destroy and recreate the table every time, you can use the [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) function.